# Button to change when clicked

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Button onTouchLitsener does not change when clicked. I want the button to change when clicked.

```
    public class SoundActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer mp1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        final Button zero = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        zero.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song_3);

        //final ImageButton zero = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        //zero.setOnTouchListener(this);

        //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song_3);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {  
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            mp.pause();
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
    }
    //public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;

       // if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           // iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_leftpressed);
           // return true;
        //} else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
            //return true;
        //}

        //return false;
    //}

    public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Button zero = (Button) v;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_leftpressed);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:clickable="true"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button4"
        android:clickable="true"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written button code in wrong block.

you have written `zero.setOnTouchListener(this);` so whenever you will touch button onTouch will get called not `onTouchEvent`

So add button code in onTouch.

Make following change in your code.

Remove this entire block

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Button zero = (Button) v;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_leftpressed);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Move above code in onTouch block.Below is how it should be.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Button zero = (Button) v;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_leftpressed);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            zero.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: am going to try it right now but i have one question do i still keep the other code in the onTouch the same? also thank you for your anwser

Comment: if you are talking  about mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
then yes its not an issue

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use an [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

The onTouchListener is receiving two events when pressing the Button - ACTION_DOWN when you're touching it and ACTION_UP when releasing. So the player starts and stops right after that.

Comment: oh but how can i make it play music and change at the same time, dowsnt it have to be two events for that? sory am still a newby

Comment: why not just add a boolean called playing with false as default? you could just use an if and check the boolean and afterwards set playing = !playing. if it's not playing set the button text to stop and begin playing, if it's playing set the text to start and stop it ;)